# C++ Random number generator: Trying to get the results as vectors but getting an error by making void function to do it

Tags: c++

Previously I asked how to make a random number generator in C++ here, and with other people's help I got it right.
Now, I'm trying to return the result as vectors instead of a series of numbers, but it doesn't seem working right. I know that **void** is not meant to return anything, but using **double** instead of **void** didn't work either..
To give more details, I'm trying to return two containers named **x_coord** and **y_coord** that contain all the result from **x_coord.push_back(oldRoot)** and **y_coord.push_back(newRoot)**. I'm doing this because I need them for later use. What is the best way to do this? Thank you for help in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// Generate random x and y coordinates for 128 particles

class Random {
public:
    double oldRoot;
    double newRoot;
    int iteNum;

    Random(double aOldRoot, double aNewRoot, int aIteNum) {
        oldRoot = aOldRoot;
        newRoot = aNewRoot;
        iteNum = aIteNum;
    }


    void generate() {

        vector<double> x_coord;
        vector<double> y_coord;
        int count = 0;

        while (count <= iteNum) {
            double totalRoot = oldRoot + newRoot;
            if (totalRoot > 1.0) {
                oldRoot = newRoot;
                newRoot = totalRoot - 1.0;

                x_coord.push_back(oldRoot);
                y_coord.push_back(newRoot);
            }
            else {
                oldRoot = newRoot;
                newRoot = totalRoot;

                x_coord.push_back(oldRoot);
                y_coord.push_back(newRoot);
            }

            count += 1;
        }
        return x_coord, y_coord;
    }
};

int main() {

    Random random10(0.1412, 0.2343, 16);
    random10.generate();

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple option would be to return the 2 `vector`s as a `std::pair`, like this:

```
std::pair<std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>> generate() {
  // fill up the vectors
  return {x_coord, y_coord};
}
```

However, I would suggest storing the `x` and `y` co-ordinates together in a data structure, like this:

```
std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> xy_coord;
```

since the `x` and `y` co-ordinates should probably be pairwise connected.

You can insert pairs of randomly generated numbers like this:

```
xy_coord.push_back({oldRoot, newRoot});
```

Answer (score 1):

The error appeared because you defined the function `generate()` has returning type is `void` while you are `return x_coord, y_coord;`

To fix it, you must have returning type like `std::pair<vector<double>, vector<double>>` because your `x_coord` and `y_coord` are `vector<double>` and you are returning them at the same time as a tuple.

Basically, you could do something like:

```
std::pair<vector<double>, vector<double>> generate() {

        vector<double> x_coord;
        vector<double> y_coord;

        //Put your code here...

        return {x_coord, y_coord};
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for teaching me about std::pair! However, now I'm not getting any output when I run the code after I changed **void** to **std::pair<vector<double>, vector<double>>**. Do you know how I can get the x_coord and y_coord?

Comment: if you want to get the returned tuple after executing the `generate() `, first you should define `std::pair<vector<double>, vector<double>> v;` then `v = random10.generate();`, you could get `x_coord` by using `v.first` and `y_coord` by using `v.second`.